# Query to fetch documents that have a specific number of filtered nested documents

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an Elastic Search document type with a structure as shown below.

```
// Let's call this the PARENT document
{
  "id": "...",
  ... other fields
  // events are NESTED documents
  "events": [
    {
      "type": "TYPE_A",
      "date": "<date 1>"
    },
    {
      "type": "TYPE_A",
      "date": "<date 2>"
    },
    {
      "type": "TYPE_B",
      "date": "<date 3>"
    }
  ]
}
```

How do I write a query that fetches me all the parent documents where

1. between dates [date 1 - date 3]
2. N number of TYPE_A events have occurred

I can write a nested terms filter matching TYPE_A combined with a range filter on the dates to find all occurrences of the event between specified date range. But is there no way to now specify that N number of such events must have occurred?

I'm even open to changing my existing model schema if someone can point out a way in this can be achieved.

An example for a real life query matching this would be along the lines - find me all StackOverflow users who have answered more than 5 JavaScript questions in the last 30 days